# Reading tab separated file using getchar()

Tags: c

I am trying to read a text file using input redirection, `./program < file.txt`, and the file I made looks like this:

```
Country\tSport\tGender\tMedal\n
America\tCycling\tMens\tGold\n
New Zealand\tSwimming\tWomens\tSilver\n
India\tBadminton\tMens\tbronze\n
```

Which just reads some random data, in according to the first row with 4 columns, headed `Country`, `Sport`, `Gender` and `Medal`.

I also inserted `\t` and `\n` to make the file more readable, but the file actually has tabs and newlines in it.

I am trying to read each line of that file, and store them in an array of strings, which I have declared as:

```
char *records[ROWS][COLUMNS];
```

I would like the array of strings, `records` to look something like:

```
{{"Country", "Sport", "Gender", "Medal"}, {"America", "Cycling", "Mens", "Gold"}, 
{"New Zealand", "Swimming", "Womens", "Silver"}, {"India", "Badminton", "Mens", "Bronze"}}
```

So far I have just been using `scanf` to read the lines, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROWS 1000
#define COLS 30
#define MAX_CH 50

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *records[ROWS][COLS];

    char country[MAX_CH];
    char sport[MAX_CH];
    char gender[MAX_CH];
    char medal[MAX_CH];

    while (scanf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", country, sport, gender, medal) == 4) {
        printf("%s %s %s %s\n", country, sport, gender, medal);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I know this will not work as the country name `New Zealand` has a space between both strings, and my `scanf` wil only read the first four characters. My method of `scanf` will also not be effective because it only works for 4 columns.

Is there a way I can use `getchar()` instead to do this? I'm just not sure how to use `getchar` to analyse each character in the input stream, and convert the necessary characters to strings depending on the tabs and newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getchar` can be used to read into the rows and columns.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define ROWS 1000
#define COLS 30
#define MAX_CH 50

void print_array(char str[][COLS][MAX_CH], int nrows, int ncols, int col[], int reorder);
void sort_array(char str[][COLS][MAX_CH], int nrows, int ncols, int col[]);


int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char records[ROWS][COLS][MAX_CH] = { { { '\0'}}};//set each element
    char item[MAX_CH] = { '\0'};//buffer for each item
    //char yn[40];
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    int usedcol = 0;
    int sortby[COLS] = { 0};
    int ch = 0;
    int each = 0;
    int loop = 0;
    int result = 0;

    if ( argc < 2 || argc > COLS + 1) {
        fprintf ( stderr, "syntax is\n%s column0 [column1]...[column%d] < inputfile\n", argv[0], COLS - 1);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for ( each = 1; each <= COLS + 1; each++) {// +1 to get to extra element
        sortby[each - 1] = -1;//extra element will be -1
        if ( each < argc) {
            if ( ( result = sscanf ( argv[each], "%d", &sortby[each - 1])) != 1 || sortby[each - 1] < 0 || sortby[each - 1] >= COLS) {
                fprintf ( stderr, "syntax is\n%s column0 [column1]...[column%d] < inputfile\n", argv[0], COLS - 1);
                fprintf ( stderr, "column%d must be 0 to %d\n", each - 1, COLS - 1);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }

    for ( each = 0; each < argc - 1; each++) {
        for ( loop = 0; loop < argc - 1; loop++) {
            if ( loop != each && sortby[each] == sortby[loop]) {
                fprintf ( stderr, "found duplicate columns in args\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
    //printf ( "\n");

    if ( isatty ( fileno ( stdin))) {
        printf ( "expected that a file would be redirected to this program\n");
        printf ( "syntax is\n%s column0 [column1]...[column%d] < inputfile\n", argv[0], COLS - 1);
        //printf ( "enter y to continue WITHOUT the redirected file?\n");
        //if ( ( fgets ( yn, sizeof ( yn), stdin))) {
            //if ( strcmp ( yn, "y\n") != 0) {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            //}
        //}
    }

    row = 0;
    col = 0;
    each = 0;
    while ( ( ch = getchar ( )) != EOF) {//read each character
        if ( ch == '\r') {//skip carriage return
            continue;
        }
        if ( ch == '\t') {
            strcpy ( records[row][col], item);
            each = 0;//back to first character
            col++;//next column
            if ( col >= COLS) {
                col = 0;
                row++;
                if ( row >= ROWS) {
                    fprintf ( stderr, "too many rows\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
            continue;
        }
        if ( ch == '\n') {
            strcpy ( records[row][col], item);
            col++;
            if ( col > usedcol) {
                usedcol = col;
            }
            col = 0;//back to first column
            each = 0;//back to first character
            row++;//next row
            if ( row >= ROWS) {
                fprintf ( stderr, "too many rows\n");
                break;
            }
            continue;
        }
        item[each] = ch;
        each++;//next character
        item[each] = '\0';//terminate with '\0'
        if ( each >= MAX_CH - 1) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "too many characters in item\n");
            each = 0;
            col++;
            if ( col >= COLS) {
                col = 0;
                row++;
                if ( row >= ROWS) {
                    fprintf ( stderr, "too many rows\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
            continue;
        }
    }

    print_array ( records, row, usedcol, sortby, 0);

    sort_array ( records, row, usedcol, sortby);

    print_array ( records, row, usedcol, sortby, 1);

    return 0;
}

void print_array(char str[][COLS][MAX_CH], int nrows, int ncols, int col[], int reorder) {
    int i, j;
    int order[COLS] = { 0};

    for ( i = 0; i < COLS; i++) {
        if ( reorder) {
            order[i] = col[i];
        }
        else {
            order[i] = i;
        }
    }

    if ( reorder) {
        for ( i = 0; i < COLS; i++) {
            for ( j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
                if ( order[j] == i) {
                    break;
                }
                if ( order[j] == -1) {
                    order[j] = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < ncols; j++) {
            printf("%-12s ", str[i][order[j]]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void sort_array(char str[][COLS][MAX_CH], int nrows, int ncols, int col[]) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, swap = 0, each = 0;
    char temp[MAX_CH] = { '\0'};

    do {
        swap = 0;
        for ( i = 1; i < nrows - 1; i++) {//iterate through rows. i=1 skip first row

            for ( each = 0; col[each] != -1; each++) {//col[] has last element of -1

                if ( strcmp( str[i][col[each]], str[i + 1][col[each]]) < 0) {
                    break;
                }
                if ( strcmp( str[i][col[each]], str[i + 1][col[each]]) == 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                for ( j = 0; j < ncols; j++) {//iterate through cols and swap rows
                    strcpy ( temp, str[i][j]);
                    strcpy ( str[i][j], str[i + 1][j]);
                    strcpy ( str[i + 1][j], temp);
                }
                swap = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while ( swap);//loop until no swaps
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo code with `getChar()`:

```
while (char = getChar()) is not 'EOF': // EOF = End of file
    if char is not '\t' and char is not '\n'
        save into current string
    else if char is '\t'
        terminate current string
        increment column index
    else if char is '\n'
        terminate current string
        increment row index
```

**Edit:**

The problem with `getChar()` is that you only know how long the string will be once you reach the next tab.

So you either have to iterate a first time to know the length of the string and then allocate an appropriate amount of memory, or you need to always allocate a safe amount of memory (your max string length).

Then in both options you can use `strcat()` to concatenate strings, but you can also access a `char` in a `char*` or `char[]` (String) by its index:

```
char string[] = "MINE"; // string[0] -> 'M'
string[0] = 'N'; // string -> "NINE"

// with dynamic memory allocation
char *string = (char*) malloc(5*sizeof(char));
string[0] = 'N'; // string -> "N"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read by lines and then apply strtok() using '\t' as delimiter.

[Reference for strtok() (it's from cplusplus.com, but strtok is in string.h, so it works also in c)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)

Answer (score 1):

The posted code contains several problems:

1. unused stack variable `records[][]`
2. unused parameter: `argc`
3. unused parameter: `argv`
4. places all input data into first entries in the arrays: country[], sport[], gender[], medal[]  I.E. all the other entries are not used
5. does not handle 'columns' that contain any white space
6. includes a header file those contents are not used: `string.h`

The following code cleanly compiles and performs the desired function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <string.h>

#define ROWS 1000
//#define COLS 30
#define MAX_CH 49

struct record
{
    char country[ MAX_CH+1 ];
    char sport  [ MAX_CH+1 ];
    char gender [ MAX_CH+1 ];
    char medal  [ MAX_CH+1 ];
};

int main( void ) 
{
    struct record records[ROWS];

    for( size_t i=0; i< ROWS; i++)
    {
        if( scanf(" %" MAX_CH "[^\t] %" MAX_CH "[^\t] %" MAX_CH "[^\t] %" MAX_CH "[^\n]", 
                records[i].country, 
                records[i].sport, 
                records[i].gender, 
                records[i].medal) == 4) 
        {
            printf("%s %s %s %s\n", 
                    records[i].country, 
                    records[i].sport, 
                    records[i].gender, 
                    records[i].medal);
        }

        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
} // end function: main
```